# AspNetCore with angular 6 Import and Include SCSS files

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, sass, angular6

I am working on Asp.net Core With Angular 6 Project 
I installed ngx-admin template to angular Project
then includes scss style in my global style like this

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/globals';

@include nb-install() {
 @include nb-theme-global();
};
```

when I run the project I got this error :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         Including .css files with @import is non-standard behaviour which will be removed in future versions of LibSass.
>         Use a custom importer to maintain this behaviour. Check your implementations documentation on how to create a custom importer.

any Help !?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates you are loading a CSS file.   It's possible one of you above imports is importing a CSS file.

`@import "foo.css";`

Which basically is converting it to.

`@import url(foo.css);`

If you want to import the contents of a CSS file into the output CSS then it's recommended just reference the CSS file directly in your `angular.json` in the `"styles": []` section.

Comment: I also did that but still facing the same Problem :/

Comment: I uninstall it then install it again it works thanks